# ubuntu corrupted source.list and apt update/install problems

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, arm64

i got some 404 not found errors between lines while apt update,

```
404  Not Found [IP: 52.52.36.226 443]
```

full apt update:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HgF7FdyNqW/

and also, whenever i try to download a package i get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package <package_name>
```

then i made some research and changed my /etc/apt/sources.list file with several ones that i found on internet. Those are;
https://gist.github.com/nichham2/439feada8a2645f9627a2cdf246feba8
https://gist.github.com/hakerdefo/9c99e140f543b5089e32176fe8721f5f

currently i use the last one and still i'm getting errors with things related with apt.

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu-linux-22-04-desktop 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:56:13 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Device is M1 Macbook Pro 2020 (launching ubuntu via parallels 17)

**EDIT: Full apt update output link added**

Comment: Please update your question with the full output of `sudo apt update`  and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @SorenA added. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HgF7FdyNqW/

Comment: @SorenA also i didn't add apt upgrade because it looks normal. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Failed to fetch <sources.list links> 404 Not Found \[IP: <some\_ip>\]"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348375/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-sources-list-links-404-not-found-ip-some-ip)