# E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate. Snap not installed and is not available

Tags: apt

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole. I accidentally deleted snap and tried to reinstall it, but I've also been having issues installing other packages.
After inputting `sudo apt install snapd`, I get the message:

```
Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate
```

and after inputting `sudo apt install snap`

```
E: Unable to locate package snap
```

I checked if there were any files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`, but there were not.

After restoring my sources.list I tried to do `sudo apt update`, and I got these errors along with many ignores

```
Err:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:68 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Fetched 608 kB in 4s (151 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am also running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you've deleted a lot more than snap.

Comment: Please add the output of command `uname -m` - it looks like you are trying to pull ARM packages from a repository that doesn't contain them

Comment: `uname -m` outputs `aarch64`. I probably should have noted that I am on ARM64.

Comment: In that case, you "restored" your sources.list file to the wrong repo, I think - see for example [How to fix "Failed to fetch <sources.list links> 404 Not Found \[IP: <some_ip>\]"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348375/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-sources-list-links-404-not-found-ip-some-ip)

Comment: If using *arm64* you should be using http://ports.ubuntu.com/ and not the main archive.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you guys so much for the help.